# Is it possible to have one Craft install running

Tags: multi-site, subdomain

Can a Craft install run on multiple domains and/or subdomains?

For example having the same Craft install running a blog Channel at blog.example.com and also an about Single at example.com

Answer (score 2):

Sure it can. Craft 3 has [multi-site](https://craftcms.com/features/multi-site) support.
And for using a subdomain, you don't even need that, just point that subdomain at the correct template URL (eg. forward blog.example.com to example.com/blog).
The about single at example.com would just be your homepage.